# Full exceptional collections in derived category of coherent sheaves on non-compact varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$, and $D^b(X)$ its bounded derived category of coherent sheaves. Then a full exceptional collection will lead to significant simplifications in the study of $D^b(X)$. This happens, for example, in the case when $X$ is a del Pezzo surface.

It's natural to consider what happens in the case when $X$ is **non-compact** with $c_1(X)>0$, **when is it possible to find a full exceptional collection in** $D^b(X)$? Perhaps we should consider only compactly supported coherent sheaves.

Comment: I just came to MO to ask this question myself. Derived categories on quasi-projective schemes are studied in Ballard ["Equivalences of derived categories of sheaves on quasi-projective schemes"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3148). As far as I'm aware there are no general results guaranteeing the existence of full exceptional collections on quasi-projective varieties (but I hope to be wrong).